# Mockito- calling real method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a class which has 2 methods. I want to mock the class and then mock the first method but not the 2nd one.

e.g.

```
class C {
 void m1() { ...}
 boolean m2() { ... return flag;}
}
```

unit test code:

```
C cMock = Mockito.mock(C.class);
Mockito.doNothing().when(cMock).m1();
Mockito.when(cMock.m2()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

The strange thing is that m2 is not being called.

do I miss anything here?

Comment: is your actual class C non-final?  Also, as an alternative, you could make a Spy instead of a Mock, and then you only have to do the `doNothing()` for m1.

Comment: Can you give us the whole unit test code? Because here, that's normal if m2 is not being called. Your are just declaring the behavior of the mocks. But no real method gets called.

Comment: @Kevin. yes its not-final. Spy worked!

Comment: @LaurentG, I missed cMock.m2(); call. now it worked too.

Answer (score 45):

This is also where `Mockito.spy` can be used. it allows you to do partial mocks on real objects.

```
C cMock = Mockito.spy(new C());
Mockito.doNothing().when(cMock).m1();
```

Answer (score 7):

was missing call to :
cMock.m2();